# Creating and setting new models in declarative views

Tags: sapui5

According to the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f285256f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) and [View's API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.View#specialsettings), setting a `ResourceModel` declaratively in XML or JSON views is possible via `resourceBundleName`, `resourceBundleAlias`, etc.

But is there a possibility to declaratively set any other models in these views or controls? If yes, how?

Comment: What different models are you referring to? `ResourceModel`is just one type. There are also others such as `ODataModel`. Or do you mean how you can use multiple models within one single view (which is possible as well)?

Comment: Please give more detail, what specific programming problem are you facing?

Comment: Yes I know about the existing models. But according to the UI5 documentation only properties for ResourceModels are available:
  "resourceBundleName":"myBundle",
   "resourceBundleAlias":"i18n",
Is there any possibilty to set a model to controls in the JSONVIEW?

Comment: @NicoHennrich I enhanced your question to make it a bit clearer for other readers. Feel free to revert if it doesn't describe what you meant.

Comment: Related enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2890. You can show maintainers that you're interested in this feature by giving +1 

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/MVC.html#DataBindinginXMLViews) you can only define one ResourceModel in the declarative way, but you can assign additional models afterwards using:

```
oView.setModel(oModel, sModelName);
```

like you would also do with OData/JSON/XML models.

---

I hope I got your question right, as you have not provided much information.

Comment: But this is only working in JSViews. How can this be done in XML or JSONViews?

Comment: You can (and should) do this in your controller: this.getView().setModel(oModel, sModelName);

Comment: @matz3 I believe the question author was asking whether it's possible to create and set models in declarative views. There is now an enhancement request which describes this a bit more:  https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2890

Answer (score 0):

If you have unified ResourceBundle for a whole project you can attach it in views easily.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
    bundleUrl: 'i18n.properties',
    locale: sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLanguage()
});
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "i18n");
```

And then use it from views, e.g.:

```
<Button text="{i18n>buttonText}" />
```

Where `buttonText` is property from ResourceBundle.